# ERROR: Unrecoverable error: IOError(9, 'Bad file descriptor')

Tags: python, django, celery

Sometimes I get this error from celery 3.0.24 on django.
Anyone knows what could be the reason for that?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1115

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help.